# Apache Rewrite with Multiple Parameters

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite the following types of URLs:

http://www.gocruise.co.uk/fusion/detailline3.pl?lineid=13&sid=6924&ccid=Fred+Olsen

into:

http://www.gocruise.co.uk/fred-olsen

using an Apache RewriteRule. I have been trying to get to grips with these rewrites as quick as i can but have run out of time. Any help will be much appreciated.

(the main bit im struggling with is how to manage the multiple parameters)

Comment: Are you suggesting that you would then want to redirect `...&ccid=John-Smith` to `/john-smith`?  Also, what are your intentions with the remaining parameters? Append them to the redirected URL - `/fred-olson?lineid=13&sid=6924` ?

Comment: Yes thats what im suggesting, and so long as the other parameters get passed, they can disappear (if possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want it the other way round: A request of `/fred-olsen` comes in, and you want to redirect the user to the longer URL. This is pretty simple:

```
# in the Server Configuration or VHost Configuration:
RewriteRule ^/fred-olsen$ /fusion/detailline3.pl?lineid=13&sid=6924&ccid=Fred+Olsen [R=301,L]
```

or:

```
# in the .htaccess file of the DocumentRoot
RewriteRule ^fred-olsen$ fusion/detailline3.pl?lineid=13&sid=6924&ccid=Fred+Olsen [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless lineid and sid are always going to be the same values, or they're not important to the code, I don't think it's going to work.  Typically, url rewrites include all the parameters, so you'd end up with something like http://www.gocruise.co.uk/13/6924/fred-olsen

Answer (score 0):

Alright, the following rules should do what you're asking.  The other two parameters will be sent in the querystring.  The only other way would be to add them into the URL, which it doesn't seem like that is what you want.

```
# http://www.gocruise.co.uk/fusion/detailline3.pl?lineid=13&sid=6924&ccid=Fred+Olsen
# redirects to ->
# http://www.gocruise.co.uk/Fred-Olsen?lineid=13&sid=6924

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /fusion/detailline3.pl
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)&ccid=(\w*)\+(\w*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /%2-%3?%1 [L,R=301]
```